# Вызов вывода данных из контроллера в angularjs через innerHTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть выводящийся на странице через ng-repeat список элементов из контроллера. При клике по элементу берутся его данные и выводятся в html. Всё стандартно:

```
<div id="mydiv">{{selected.element}}</div>
```

Когда я хочу заменить содержимое div на что-то иное, я делаю это через getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML

Но как я могу вернуть в html волшебство ангуляра? Если я пишу

```
getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "{{selected.element}}";
```

, то оно прямо так в html и вставляет. Будто это просто текст: {{selected.element}}.

Comment: Вы пробовали `getElementById("mydiv").innerText = "{{selected.element}}"`

Comment: чтобы пользоваться ангуляром - не надо пользоваться нативными средствами :-)

Comment: @Grundy просто интересно самому, зачем понадобился такой "трюк")

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, до сих пор есть проекты с легаси кодом, где шаблон приходит с сервера и нужно его таким образом отрендерить, то есть шаблон не лежит в памяти (`$templateCache`) и загружается по требованию (`lazy`)

Comment: @overthesanity я могу понять то, что сейчас мало кто делает проэкты с 0 на _angularJs_, но что-бы такие вещи рендерит,  слава-богу не встречал ))

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, такое можно встретить в большой компании на каком-то большом старом проекте, где нет возможности и денег переписать его

Comment: Скажите, вам помог мой ответ?

Comment: @Павел Игоревич , нет, увы, innerText проблему не решил. И с ним подменённый фрагмент отображается как текст, а в действительности там нужна смесь html-кода и ангулярного вызова.

Comment: Короче говоря, сделал вообще без вытягиваниям ангуляром, а тупо чтоб при клике через innerHTML всё было. Говнокодить, так уж по крупному. Всем спасибо за попытку помочь.

Answer (score 1):

## Привязка данных раскрывается через ряд директив:

**ng-bind:** осуществляет привязку к свойству innerText html-элемента

**ng-bind-html**: осуществляет привязку к свойству innerHTML html-элемента

**ng-bind-template**: аналогична ng-bind за тем исключением, что позволяет установить привязку сразу к нескольким выражениям

**ng-model**: создает двустороннюю привязку

**ng-non-bindable**: определяет участок html-кода, в котором привязка не будет использоваться

В данном случае `ng-repeat` - это повторение `ng-bind` это значит, что вам нужно использоват следующий синтаксис :

```
getElementById("mydiv").innerText = "{{selected.element}}"
```

Comment: сервис `$compile` решает такие проблемы на ура

Comment: @overthesanity не спорю

Comment: Нет, увы, но innerText проблему не решил. Тот же самый простой текст, да к тому же и html-код вставляемый ({{selected.element}}<br>) отображается с ним, разумеется, тоже как текст. :(